# How to efficiently push displayable item into String?

Tags: rust

See this example:

```
fn concat<T: std::fmt::Display>(s: &mut String, thing: T) {
    // TODO
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = "Hello ".into();
    concat(&mut s, 42);

    assert_eq!(&s, "Hello 42");
}
```

I know that I can use this:

```
s.push_str(&format!("{}", thing))
```

but this is not the most efficient, because `format!` allocate a `String` that is not necessary.

The most efficient is to write directly the string representation of the displayable item into the `String` buffer. How to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple formatting macros, and in your case you want the [`write!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.13.0/std/macro.write.html) macro:

```
use std::fmt::{Display, Write};

fn concat<T: Display>(s: &mut String, thing: &T) {
    write!(s, "{}", thing).unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = "Hello ".into();
    concat(&mut s, &42);

    assert_eq!(&s, "Hello 42");
}
```

Anything that implements one of the `Write` trait (and `String` does) is a valid target for `write!`.

*Note: actually anything that implements a `write_fmt` method, as macro don't care much about semantics; which is why either `fmt::Write` or `io::Write` work.*

Comment: There are two (usable) `Write` traits (`std::io` and `std::fmt`).

Comment: @Stefan: Yes. I didn't feel like calling it out explicitly since it's mentioned in the `write!` macro documentation that I linked, but since you felt the need for it, it now is :)